# Give separate classes common methods

Tags: java

I'm making a simple-ish text based RPG-like game focused on encounters and combat, and I'm trying to use OOP to create a "tree" of creature types and creatures,

So here's some of Battler's subclasses and their sub subclasses:

```
Battler
|-Player
|
|-Phantom
| |-Wisp
|
|-Undead
| |-Wraith
|
|-Elementals
  |-Lightning
    |-Spark Mote
```

Here's the thing: I plan to have a method for each spell in the game. For two examples, let's say Ennervate and Shockwave. I want to give the Wraith Ennervate, the Spark Mote Shockwave, the Player both (eventually at least) and the Wisp neither.

I can see one solution, and that is to dump all the spells into Battler, but I can foresee that ending horribly due to quite a lot ending up in one file.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You could create a class per spell, and give each creature type a list of spells. Make a `Spell` interface/superclass.

Comment: @marstran an enum would probably be even better

Comment: @Lino how did you edit the format of the tree like that?

Comment: @CoruscareGames I marked the tree with my mouse and clicked ctrl+k to indent it as a code block. If that is what you meant

Comment: create an interface and implement them in subclasses which implement the interface so that you can change the behavior in future at runtime.

Comment: And just to be sure ... as that sometimes happens to be forgotten:

Answer (score 2):

The answer is probably: don't use methods then.

Instead: create some sort of class representing the "shared" capability, and have your base class contain a list of such objects.

In other words: you want a high amount of flexibility here, and polymorphism isn't helping there much. Especially given your context: sooner or later, you will probably think about ways to *earn* capabilities. Meaning: not only would your objects have many different methods, but sometimes you would want them to be "enabled", sometimes not.

As in:

```
class Spell {
  whatever ...
}

public abstract class Battler {
  private final List<Spell> spells = new ArrayList<>();

  ...

  public void addSpell(Spell newSpell) { spells.add(spell); }

  public List<Spell> getSpells() ...
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: See my updates then. But don't expect much more specifics, as your input is also pretty generic, too.

Comment: I think I get it. I believe that each spell class would have a method that activates its effect, and to cast the spell the method would be called, right?

Comment: For example. That is my point: we dont have your "vision" what a spell should do. I just outlined one approach how you could enable your system to deal with spells ... without fixing them via "methods".

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Should I modify my question to reflect needing to cast said spells?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're implementing the spells, but for as I see it an easy way to do that is declare a `Spell` class and then make every spell inherit from it.

You can now assign a list of spell to every creature/monster/player and add effects to the single spell without too much pain.

So your Player will have `Ennervate` and `Shockwave` in a list/set of spells, same for the other creatures.